# Archiving AVCHD from camera for later processing

Tags: post-production, avchd

What is the recommended way to copy AVCHD data from SD card to a hard drive for later processing? My video camera would be going on an extended trip and the post-processing will be done after the trip.

Should the whole top level folder ("/private" in my camera SD Card") be copied to individual folder on the hard drive?

Or is there a better method so that post-processing would be easier?

Comment: It doesn't matter at all ... why do you ask?

Comment: Reason I ask is that the camera will be handled by a person with very limited technical understanding about post-processing. I just want them to dump the sd card in to a external drive and bring back to me for later processing.

Comment: Yes whole cards should be copied to preserve the structure for the NLE later on to import, giving each card a specific naming convention and following that through the whole trip/process/shoot

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that the camera may produce multiple files with the same name. So keeping the original folders is a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the way I do this from my Canon 7D / 100D is pop the CF or SD card into my Mac and copy the whole card to a folder with a very simple structure

- Project_Name_Date

  - RAW_Cards

    - Camera_Name_Card00x
    - Camera_Name_Card00x

If I would add in a DATE Folder under the Poject_Name for multiple days/Dates, When I get back to the studio to start editing I can then just ingest these into my system.

You probably find the same system will work on a Windows PC as well.

The other alternative would be to use a card copy application to do all of this but might make it to complex for the user in the middle.